# Roslyn Message Format is not working with analysis

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've created a message format similar to in the default project message:

> Variable named '{0}' can be made into a constant

I've created my rule:

```
private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId,
          Title,
          MessageFormat, 
          Category, 
          DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, 
          isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);
```

Registered it:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeLocalizationNode, SyntaxKind.LocalDeclarationStatement);
}
```

Full Analyzer:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class LocalizationToolAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "LocalizationTool";

    // You can change these strings in the Resources.resx file. If you do not want your analyzer to be localize-able, you can use regular strings for Title and MessageFormat.
    // See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Localizing%20Analyzers.md for more on localization
    private static readonly LocalizableString Title = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerTitle), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
    private static readonly LocalizableString MessageFormat = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerMessageFormat), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
    private static readonly LocalizableString Description = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerDescription), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
    private const string Category = "Naming";

    private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeLocalizationNode, SyntaxKind.LocalDeclarationStatement);
    }

    private static void AnalyzeLocalizationNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var localDeclaration = (LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)context.Node;

        // Only consider local variable declarations that aren't already const.
        if (localDeclaration.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword))
        {
            return;
        }

        var variableTypeName = localDeclaration.Declaration.Type;
        var variableType = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(variableTypeName).ConvertedType;

        // Ensure that all variables in the local declaration have initializers that
        // are assigned with constant values. i.e int x, y = 0, (is not valid)
        foreach (var variable in localDeclaration.Declaration.Variables)
        {
            if (false == LocalizationToolAnalyzer.CanMakeGlobalConst(context, variable, variableType))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Perform data flow analysis on the local declaration.
        var dataFlowAnalysis = context.SemanticModel.AnalyzeDataFlow(localDeclaration);

        // Retrieve the local symbol for each variable in the local declaration
        // and ensure that it is not written outside of the data flow analysis region.
        foreach (var variable in localDeclaration.Declaration.Variables)
        {
            var variableSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(variable);
            if (dataFlowAnalysis.WrittenOutside.Contains(variableSymbol))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, context.Node.GetLocation()));
    }

    private static bool CanMakeGlobalConst(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, VariableDeclaratorSyntax variable,
        ITypeSymbol variableType)
    {
        var initializer = variable.Initializer;
        if (initializer == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var constantValue = context.SemanticModel.GetConstantValue(initializer.Value);
        if (!constantValue.HasValue)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Ensure that the initializer value can be converted to the type of the
        // local declaration without a user-defined conversion.
        var conversion = context.SemanticModel.ClassifyConversion(initializer.Value, variableType);
        if (!conversion.Exists || conversion.IsUserDefined)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Special cases:
        //  * If the constant value is a string, the type of the local declaration
        //    must be System.String.
        //  * If the constant value is null, the type of the local declaration must
        //    be a reference type.
        if (constantValue.Value is string)
        {
            if (variableType.SpecialType != SpecialType.System_String)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (variableType.IsReferenceType && constantValue.Value != null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Yet my display message never substitues the variable how can I fix this?

Comment: How are you reported the diagnostic?

Comment: @SLaks I've updated to provide the full analyzer but the line is ` context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, context.Node.GetLocation()));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing anything for it to substitute.

In its [simplest overload](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Diagnostic/Diagnostic.cs,8a6faf8a20fbdf67), `Diagnostic.Create` takes a `Location`, followed by message format arguments.

You need to pass the variable name (or whatever else you want to substitute) explicitly.

As a quick hack you can convert the declaration to a symbol and grab the name:

```
 var firstVariable = localDeclaration.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault();
 var firstSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(firstVariable);

 context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, context.Node.GetLocation(), firstSymbol.Name));
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  I added how I solved it so people can use this as reference for the future.  If you have some more time and are willing to help me out I have another question that could use your expertise.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075087/roslyn-analyzer-which-compares-against-separate-class-file)