# Roslyn Analyzer which compares against separate class file

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm writing a Roslyn analyzer which compares checks if const are already declared in a Localization Resx.

```
public const string DiagnosticId = "LocalizationTool";

// You can change these strings in the Resources.resx file. If you do not want your analyzer to be localize-able, you can use regular strings for Title and MessageFormat.
// See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Localizing%20Analyzers.md for more on localization
private static readonly LocalizableString Title = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerTitle), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
private static readonly LocalizableString MessageFormat = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerMessageFormat), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
private static readonly LocalizableString Description = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.AnalyzerDescription), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
private const string Category = "Naming";

private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
   context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeConstForLocalization, SyntaxKind.FieldDeclaration);
}
```

I'm confused on how to grab out the designer.cs from the resx file.

```
private static void AnalyzeConstForLocalization(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
}
```

How can I get the Designer.cs from the SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext.  If I'm using the wrong RegisterSyntaxNodeAction, what action should I use in which I can analzye consts an resx file and how can I find the file.

Comment: How about registering a SemanticModel action, and finding the `Designer.cs` by looking through the other files in the model?

Comment: How would I know which designers are resx and not say for winforms etc

Comment: @TamásSzabó and how can I iterate of over the projects by using `SemanticModel`

Comment: I think you can access the Documents of a project through `SemanticModel.Compilation.SyntaxTrees`. Then you can just check if the class names are the same, since the designer is just a part of the partial class you are analysing. I don't have any examples on me right now, I can check back with you on Tuesday.

Comment: @johnny5 Did you manage to get something working?

Comment: Yeah, eventually I think I ended up using the Msbuild API.  What are you trying to do?